# Crear una matriz con 2 bucles en Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código, con el cual quiero generar una matriz sin valores numéricos pero que tenga las filas y columnas bien puestas, en función de lo que diga el usuario

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
filas=int(input("Introduce el número de filas de la matriz: "))
columnas=int(input("Introduce el numero de columnas de la matriz: "))

for i in range (1,filas+1):
    for j in range (1,columnas+1):
        print("fila {} columna {}; ".format(i,j), end='\t')
```

Y me genera el siguiente resultado:

```
Introduce el número de filas de la matriz: 3
Introduce el numero de columnas de la matriz: 4
fila 1 columna 1;   fila 1 columna 2;   fila 1 columna 3;   fila 1 columna 4;   fila 2 columna 1;   fila 2 columna 2;   fila 2 columna 3;   fila 2 columna 4;   fila 3 columna 1;   fila 3 columna 2;   fila 3 columna 3;   fila 3 columna 4;
```

No soy capaz de que se pongan las filas y las columnas de forma matricial

Comment: ¿Qué es para ti "forma matricial"? Porque tal vez baste con recorrer primero las columnas y luego las filas. Todo dependerá de lo que necesites al final.

Comment: Prueba a imprimir un salto de línea entre los bucles `for`, justo antes del segundo...

Answer (score 0):

El problem es que estas redefiniendo `end` en `print`. Por default, al final de cada print va un retorno de carro `\n`.

Puedes agregar el nueva linea después de el primer bucle, cuando termina de imprimir la fila:

```py
for i in range (1,filas+1):
    for j in range (1,columnas+1):
        print("fila {} columna {}; ".format(i,j), end='\t')
    print()   # <-
```

#### Implementación alternativa:

Tu código puede resultar en este tipo de desalineación en casos extremos:

```
...
fila 999998 columna 1;  fila 999998 columna 2;
fila 999999 columna 1;  fila 999999 columna 2;
fila 1000000 columna 1;     fila 1000000 columna 2;
fila 1000001 columna 1;     fila 1000001 columna 2;
...
```

Para evitar eso, considera separar la construcción de la estructura de su presentación (imprimirlo, en este caso).

```
matriz = []
largo_max = 0
for i in range (1,filas+1):
    fila = []
    for j in range (1,columnas+1):
        texto = "fila {} columna {}; ".format(i,j)
        fila.append(texto)
        largo_max = max(largo_max, len(texto))
    matriz.append(fila)

for fila in matriz:
    for columna in fila:
        print(columna.ljust(largo_max), end=' ')
    print()
```

```
...
fila 999998 columna 1;   fila 999998 columna 2;
fila 999999 columna 1;   fila 999999 columna 2;
fila 1000000 columna 1;  fila 1000000 columna 2;
fila 1000001 columna 1;  fila 1000001 columna 2;
...
```